# Как менять текст каждый раз?

Tags: java, android, массивы, android-resources

У меня при подгрузке данных с rss во время ожидания выводится текст который прописан в strings. Можно ли составить список фраз которые будут выводится рандомно каждый раз при загрузке?
Такое выполнено в приложении freedom во время ожидания включения службы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно. Наапример так:

1. Заведите в ресурсах массив строк:

```
<string-array name="array_of_strings">

    <item>one</item>
    <item>two</item>
    <item>three</item>

</string-array>
```

2. Получите его в коде:

```
String[] arrayOfStrings = context.getStringArray(R.array.array_of_strings);
```

3. Cгенерируйте случайное число

```
int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(arrayOfStrings.lenght);
```

4. Получите случайный элемент массива

```
String randomString = arrayOfStrings[randomIndex];
```

Comment: Может в этом случае лучше получить рандомное число через `Math.random()`?

Comment: @СергейГрушин, может быть. Я не знаю что этот метод делает и есть ли отличия от  `Random#.nextInt()`